# html anchoring tag

Tags: html

what is the meaning of this anchoring tag format

```
<A href="#some name">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In layman's terms:

It is intended to link to a *section* of a page (specifically, it's usually a div or anchor named 'some name') rather than link to a new page. It can be used to link to a section of a new page other than the start also.

Answer (score 5):

Should be more like

```
<a href="#some name">Some Text</a>
```

If you click on the link, the browser will automatically jump the element with `id` or `name` `"some name"`, e.g.

```
<div id="some name">
    Some more text.
</div>
```

You will also see that the URL changes. The generic format of a URL is (more or less):

```
<scheme>://<host>/<path>?<query>#<fragment identifier>
```

The [*fragment identifier*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is what you are talking about to and it refers content inside the page. The `href` attribute above actually contains a URL, [a *relative* one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Url#Absolute_vs_relative_URLs). That means, this URL  should be interpreted relatively to the current URL.

If you current URL is

```
http://www.example.com/some/path
```

then clicking on the link will lead you to

```
http://www.example.com/some/path#some%20name
```

As already said, the fragment identifier refers to a part in the current page, so the browser does not reload the page but just jumps to that part.